# How to properly close a socket and its InputStream?

Tags: android, sockets, inputstream

Say I have a connected socket and associated InputStream. When I'm done with this connection, how do I properly close these down (without leaks)?

I've searched this question on SO and elsewhere, but the answers I've gotten were either ambiguous or contradictory. Should I

- Close the socket (only)?
- Close the input stream (only)?
- Close both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clean up the `Socket` without leaking any resources, call `close()`, then discard any references you have to the `Socket`. This advice is valid, in general, for all Java `Socket` subclasses, including `ServerSocket` and `SSLSocket`.

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#close()) explains, `close()` closes both the socket's `InputStream` and `OutputStream`, making it unnecessary to execute separate `close()` calls on those streams.

And, closing the `InputStream` and `OutputStream`, by themselves, is not sufficient.
An examination of the source code for the `Socket` base class ([old example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.3_r1/luni/src/main/java/java/net/Socket.java)) demonstrates why this is true, at least for Android.